# sphinx autoapi makes a weird bullet list in "Returns" section and mixes "Returns" and "Return type" sections

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am working on a Python library and I am writing documentation using `sphinx` and the `sphinx-autoapi` extension to generate API references. It works quite well, but I encountered a weird issue today. I have a `Color` class with a `get` class method which is documented like this:

```py
@classmethod
def get(cls, name: str) -> Color | None:
    """Get a predefined color by its name.

    If the given name doesn't correspond to a predefined color,
    :external:py:data:`None` is returned.

    Parameters
    ----------
    name
        The name of the color.

    Returns
    -------
        The color corresponding to ``name`` or :external:py:data:`None` if it
        doesn't exist.

    See Also
    --------
    names : Get a list of the names of predefined colors.
    """
```

I believe this suits the standards of the numpy style doc, which is the style I am using. However, when rendering the documentation, I get these two lines as a bulleted list where the second line is italic:

[image]

It's supposed to be just one simple line. I wrapped it into two because it exceeded the maximum line length of 88, which makes the `black` formatter complain (unfortunately, `black` can't fix it since it doesn't want to potentially change the code or docs). Why does it render like that and how can I fix make it just one simple line as I want?

Another issue I have with the generated docs which you can see in the above picture is that it created both a "Returns" section and a "Return type" section which is weird in my opinion. I know it infers the return type from the type hints, but why can't it just say the type in the "Returns" section as it does with the parameters?

In a different method of the same class, it's even more inconsistent: I have a type hint for the return type like in the above snippet (all my code base is type hinted) and a simple "Returns" section:

```py
@classmethod
def create(cls, value: ColorLike) -> Color:
    """Create a :py:class:`Color` instance from any ``value``.

    The documentation of this method is long, so it's omitted for simplicity.

    Returns
    -------
        The :py:class:`Color` created from the passed ``value``.

    Raises
    ------
    ValueError
        If the given ``value`` isn't in the correct format or any coordinate is out
        of its range.
    TypeError
        If ``value`` is an object of a type that can't be converted into a color.
    """
```

The result is that there is no "Returns" section, but instead a "Return type" section:

[image]

This is just weird. The two methods are documented in the same format (type hints + "Returns" section without any type info), and one of them has separate "Returns" and "Return type" sections while the other has just a "Return type" section instead of a "Returns" section.

How can I make it generate a single "Returns" section with the type information in it like the parameters? Or at least make it consistent about which of the "Returns" and "Return type" are generated.

Here are the relevant parts of the `conf.py` file:

```py
extensions = [
    "sphinx.ext.duration",
    "sphinx.ext.intersphinx",
    "sphinx.ext.napoleon",
    "sphinx_copybutton",
    "sphinx.ext.autodoc",
    "sphinx.ext.linkcode",
    "autoapi.extension",
    "sphinx_toolbox.source",
    "notfound.extension",
]

templates_path = ["_templates"]
exclude_patterns = []


# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------
# https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#options-for-html-output

html_theme = "pydata_sphinx_theme"
html_static_path = ["_static"]

# intersphinx settings
intersphinx_mapping = {
    "python": ("https://docs.python.org/3/", None),
}

# Napoleon settings
napoleon_google_docstring = False
napoleon_numpy_docstring = True
napoleon_attr_annotations = True

# sphinx_copybutton config
copybutton_exclude = ".linenos, .gp, .go"

# autoapi config
autodoc_typehints = "both"
autoapi_dirs = ["../../src"]
autoapi_options = [
    "members",
    "show-inheritance",
    "show-module-summary",
    "undoc-members",
]
```

Comment: Try dedenting the value for Returns.